# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation

Tags: sql, oracle, servlets

I'm Using Oracle 11g database. When i try to access data from db it was showing the error java.sql.SQLException: ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation. I'm not understanding what this error means..

my code is :

```
 String uname,pass;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
  try
  {
    uname=request.getParameter("uname");
    pass=request.getParameter("pass");
    Connection con=prepareConnection();
    String Query="select uname from passmanager where pass=?";
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(Query);
    ps.setString(1,pass);
    rs=ps.executeQuery(Query);
    if (rs.next() && uname.equalsIgnoreCase(rs.getString("uname")) || uname.equalsIgnoreCase(rs.getString("email"))) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("uname", rs.getString(1));

    ServletContext context = getServletContext();
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = context
                    .getRequestDispatcher("/profile");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
  }
```

Any one help me to solve this problem..

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Instead of:

```
rs = ps.executeQuery(Query);
```

you should execute:

```
rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Otherwise, you *unprepare* your statement and lose all parameters because you assign it a new SQL statement (even though it's the same).

Comment: Amazing Codo. Good explaination too

Comment: Definitely worth an upvote from me. Wish I'd googled it sooner.

Comment: subtle. Its easy to overlook this deadly point. Had wasted some good minutes before actually coming here clueless. Thanks Codo !

Comment: I wish I could give you another vote up. It solves my problem again after a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Add email column

```
select uname, email from passmanager where pass=?
```

Comment: sorry i forgot that. But now also problem remains same... I think the problem is with prepared statement

Answer (score 0):

This error appears when you try to get a field by name ( rs.getString("uname") in your case) which is not in the resultset.

And like igr said, you are trying to get the email field ( with rs.getString("email") ) and it's not in the query, so this is your error.

I found this conversation because I was getting the same error in an application when I was trying to get a field with an whitespace at the end of the string ( rs.getString("uname ") instead of rs.getString("uname" ).

And I just fix it using the correct name for the field I was getting from the query.

I hope it is useful! ;)