# Wrong column index in JDBC PreparedStatement

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

If I execute:

```
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement LoginStatement = null;
ResultSet LoginResult = null;
UpdateData();
String LoginQuery = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USER_NAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ? ";
try{
    System.out.println(LoginQuery);
    conn = DatabaseConnection.getDBCon();
    LoginStatement = conn.prepareStatement(LoginQuery);
    LoginStatement.setString(1, "ett");
    LoginStatement.setString(2, "ett");
    LoginResult = LoginStatement.executeQuery(LoginQuery);
```

i receive Exception: 63000 - ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation

If i cahnge the ? to '?'

```
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement LoginStatement = null;
ResultSet LoginResult = null;
UpdateData();
String LoginQuery = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USER_NAME = '?' AND PASSWORD = '?' ";
try{
    System.out.println(LoginQuery);
    conn = DatabaseConnection.getDBCon();
    LoginStatement = conn.prepareStatement(LoginQuery);
    LoginStatement.setString(1, "ett");
    LoginStatement.setString(2, "ett");
    LoginResult = LoginStatement.executeQuery(LoginQuery);
```

I get

> Exception: 99999 - Ungültiger Spaltenindex

which basically means wrong column index.

This is not true, I set index 1 and 2 and there are 2 placeholders and the index starts with 1 .... any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you are using right driver? And can you post where your connection string?

Answer (score 3):

Simply:

```
executeQuery(LoginQuery); // Statement
```

must be

```
executeQuery(); // PreparedStatement
```

A bit hideous API design and error message.

---

Also as PASSWORD is a reserved word try

```
"SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USER_NAME = ? AND \"PASSWORD\" = ? "
```

Comment: public boolean ProcessLogin(){
  Connection conn = null;
  PreparedStatement LoginStatement = null;
  ResultSet LoginResult = null;
  UpdateData();
  String LoginQuery = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USER_NAME = '?' AND PASSWORD = '?' ";
  try{
   System.out.println(LoginQuery);
   conn = DatabaseConnection.getDBCon();
   LoginStatement = conn.prepareStatement(LoginQuery);
   LoginStatement.setString(1, username);
   LoginStatement.setString(2, password);
   LoginResult = LoginStatement.executeQuery();

Comment: Then it might be that PASSWORD, place it in back-ticks. Extended answer. The executeQuery must still be without parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```
LoginResult = LoginStatement.executeQuery();
```

You can see more about first exception here [java.sql.SQLException: ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302577/java-sql-sqlexception-ora-03115-unsupported-network-datatype-or-representation)

Comment: @user3718058 you should change sql to "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USER_NAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ? "; and change execute block to LoginResult = LoginStatement.executeQuery();

Answer (score 0):

Use [executeQuery()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery()) in place of `executeQuery(LoginQuery)`;

No need to change `?` to `'?'`

Answer (score 0):

`executeQuery(String query)` method cannot be called on a PreparedStatement or CallableStatement. Use `executeQuery()`

Answer (score 0):

Note the distinction between the following calls:
//PreparedStatement
`PreparedStatement.executeQuery();` //Generally used for Stored procedures

//Statement 
`bool res = Statement.execute(String sql);`

```
ResultSet rs = Statement.executeQuery(String sql);
```