# Why ORA-03115 sometimes appears in integration tests with jenkins

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jenkins

We are testing our sql in itest: `SELECT a b from c left join d on ... where e = ?` . There are a lot of tests but only one (still same) sometimes fails with **`ora: 03115`**. Data are still same.

> `error code [3115]; ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation`

I am using `ojdbc6` with oracle 11:

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
PL/SQL Release 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
"CORE   11.1.0.6.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
```

I read about this error but nothing explain that sometimes it failed and sometimes not when conditions are same. Error appears just few times (90 % OK 10 % Failed). Any idea why this happens ?

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; 
SQL state [63000]; error code [3115]; ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:884)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1167)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3628)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1493)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:688)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:629)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:680)
```

PS: This has nothing in common with question who mark it as duplicated. In my options this problem occurs only sometimes not always as in example above. And I am using spring jdbc:

```
PreparedStatementCreator psc = new PreparedStatementCreator() {
            @Override
            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
                if (timeout != null)
                    ps.setQueryTimeout(timeout);
                if (fetchSize != null)
                    ps.setFetchSize(fetchSize);
                return ps;
            }
        };
        PreparedStatementSetter pss = new PreparedStatementSetter() {
            @Override
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
                setParameters(ps, limitType, 1);
            }
        };
        ResultSetExtractor<List> rse = new ResultSetExtractor<List>() {
            @Override
            public List extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                if (fetchSize != null)
                    rs.setFetchSize(fetchSize);
                return getResults(rs);
            }
        };


            List list = jdbcTemplate.query(psc, pss, rse);
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("list, number of returned rows=" + ((list != null) ? list.size() : "null"));
            }
            return list;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.sql.SQLException: ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302577/java-sql-sqlexception-ora-03115-unsupported-network-datatype-or-representation)

Comment: and how exactly it is duplicated ? I mention that I read about this error. But my code is always same and only sometimes this error occurs. In article above he never got OK result with his example and he need to rewrite it

Comment: Is it possible something else than your code is causing this error? Just saying that because stack trace does not refer to your function. Otherwise you could add some debug info when catching the exception.

Comment: code is still same and it works for the most of time. Can this error occurs because of some problem with network or something else ? And I have no other debug information because this error occurs only in itest which are build every day with jenkins. Locally I can not simulate this

Comment: i would look at the SQL your submitting and see if there's any unusual datatype in the query/database.  I have seen these in the user defined types, but the override to setParameters makes it a little hard to follow.