# "ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation" when trying to to fill DataSet

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm trying to fill a DataSet object with an OracleCommand object, I just started using Oracle, I've using SQL Server all my life.
On my NET console project I added the NuGet Oracle.ManagedDataAccess package and changed Sql objects to Oracle. Like: SqlConnection to OracleConnection.
In SQL Server it works perfectly, but in Oracle it gives me this error I don't really understand what it means.

I changed `SqlConnection` to `OracleConnection`
and `SqlCommand` to `OracleCommand`

also

```cs
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + parameters[i], values[i] ?? DBNull.Value);
```

to

```cs
command.Parameters.Add(parameters[i], values[i] ?? DBNull.Value);
command.Parameters[i].Value = values[i];
```

Because `AddWithValue` doesn't exist on `OracleCommand`

This is the method that gets the data from the db.

```cs
        private void GetData(string storedProcedure, IReadOnlyList<string> parameters, IReadOnlyList<object> values)
        {
            using (var connection = new OracleConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                using (
                    var command = new OracleCommand(storedProcedure, connection)
                    {
                        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    })
                {
                    if (parameters != null)
                        for (var i = 0; i < parameters.Count; i++)
                        {
                            command.Parameters.Add(parameters[i], values[i] ?? DBNull.Value);
                        }
                    var ds = new DataSet();
                    connection.Open();
                    new OracleDataAdapter(command).Fill(ds);
                    _data = ds.Tables;
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

These are the parameters im using.

```cs
            var db = new Connector.Provider("AIA.GET_DATA",
                new[]{
                    "Test1",
                    "Test2",
                    "Test3",
                    "Test4"},
                new object[]{
                    1,
                    2,
                    3,
                    null});
```

And this is the stored procedure.

```sql
  PROCEDURE GET_DATA(
    Test1           in NUMBER,
    Test2           in NUMBER,
    Test3           in NUMBER,
    Test4           in NUMBER,
    TestOut        out SYS_REFCURSOR
    );
```

On the constructor of Provider it gets the connection string and uses method GetData.

It fails on:

```
new OracleDataAdapter(command).Fill(ds);
```

Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation'

Again, this works perfectly on SQL Server.

Any help is appreciated, at least, what does this error message means.

---

EDIT:

Thank you Luke Woodward, that was very helpful. So there was a problem with the OUT parameter, but also with the type of the parameters I was sending. **So that solves the problem.**

Anyway, I ended up with this new method. Which is working fine, except with nulls.

```
    private void GetData(string storedProcedure, IReadOnlyList<string> parameters, IReadOnlyList<object> values, IReadOnlyList<string> cursors)
    {
        using (var connection = new OracleConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            using (
                var command = new OracleCommand(storedProcedure, connection)
                {
                    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                })
            {
                if (parameters != null)
                    for (var i = 0; i < parameters.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var parameter = new OracleParameter();
                        parameter.ParameterName = parameters[i];
                        if (values[i] is Enum)
                            parameter.Value = (int)values[i];
                        else
                            parameter.Value = values[i];

                        if (cursors != null && cursors.Contains(parameter.ParameterName))
                        {
                            parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                            parameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            parameter.OracleDbType = GetOracleType(values[i]);
                        }
                        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                    }

                var ds = new DataSet();
                connection.Open();
                new OracleDataAdapter(command).Fill(ds);
                _data = ds.Tables;
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

In Sql I could use `DBNull.Value`, but in Oracle I need to define `OracleDbType`, which is anonoying since this method worked for any object, not caring about the type, now I still don't know how to fix it to make it work with any object in Oracle. **But that could be considered offtopic, this question could be marked as answered.**

Comment: Oracle is not SQL Server. The way to do things in Oracle is not the same as in SQL Server. You can't simply replace _Sql_ with _Oracle_. You need to learn the Oracle way of doing things. I suggest investing some time and effort discovering how to accomplish your task at hand the Oracle way. A good start, for me at least, is the relevant Oracle documentation.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems to be some issue of marshaling the data. I found several possible causes, ranging from using the wrong Oracle client (32bit vs 64bit) to any of the possibilities mentioned in [this question (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302577/java-sql-sqlexception-ora-03115-unsupported-network-datatype-or-representation). But that aside, your code looks complicated. I think an OracleCommand should be able to execute a stored procedure right away, but you're not telling it which stored proc to execute, or maybe I overlook something in your code....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call an Oracle function with a Ref Cursor as Out-parameter from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360244/how-to-call-an-oracle-function-with-a-ref-cursor-as-out-parameter-from-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an `OracleParameter` for the `OUT` parameter `TestOut` but you are not doing this.

Add these lines after the other lines that set up the parameters:

```
    var outParam = new OracleParameter("TestOut", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);
    command.Parameters.Add(outParam);
```

You will then need to execute the command separately rather than pass the command to the `OracleDataAdapter`.  Do this by adding the line

```
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

immediately after the two that add `outParam`.

Finally, fill the dataset from the ref cursor in the `OUT` parameter by replacing the line

```
    new OracleDataAdapter(command).Fill(ds);
```

with

```
    new OracleDataAdapter().Fill(ds, (OracleRefCursor)outParam.Value);
```

Incidentally, I got a different error when I ran your code.  I got the error `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_DATA'`.